# How to Redirect all requests to a Function or Cloud Run service without any public directory?

Tags: firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I am using Firebase Hosting for many websites. Some websites have static files that I want to serve from Firebase Hosting static file serving, however, some others only have dynamic content for which I want to leverage Firebase's custom domain and caching.

It seems that the `public` attribute is required in  `firebase.json` . This requires me to deploy a public folder with a dummy file in it.

Is there a way to deploy to Firebase Hosting without any `public` directory?

The following gives me this error: `Error: Must supply a public directory using "public" in each "hosting" config.`

```
{
    "hosting": [
        {
            "target": "index",
            "public": "static",
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "target": "api",
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "run": {
                        "serviceId": "api",
                        "region": "us-central1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I created a feature request for Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3349

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) the `public` folder is required and it has to exist. Otherwise the deployment would end up with an error. It would be nice to avoid that.

I also had to do the same in my last project with dummy folders and index.html files inside.